# How do I run a Python script in Unix

Tags: python, python-2.7, zapier

I'm not a Python developer but I need to use this language to set up certain application. I'd like to do basic auth. Python documentation reads:

> Making requests with HTTP Basic Auth is very simple:

```
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')) <Response [200]>
```

So I created a file where I put:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

However, it is not as simple as the documentation claims. When I run the code I get the following error:

```
./auth.py: line 1: from: command not found
./auth.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `'https://api.github.com/user','
./auth.py: line 2: `requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))'
```

I use Python 2.7.

Comment: Your script is being run as a bash script... use the right shebang on your file or use `python my_script.py`

Comment: ...and to run it as a Python script instead, use `python myscript.py` on the command line (with your Python filename instead of 'myscript.py`).

Comment: I don't see you importing `requests.get`? Also, how are you running the script? It should be ran using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are error messages from a `bash` script... you probably don't have the correct shebang at the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then run the script as `./my_script`

Or, use:

```
python my_script.py
```

To run the script.